# "Accurate" local position using MPU (arduino + MPU + PC)

Tags: arduino, virtual-reality, motion-detection

I had an idea to create custom hand trackers for VR.

After several days of searching, I realized that the local position of MPU can be calculated as follows using only accelerometer:

```
dt = 0;
acceleration = {0, 0, 0};
speed = {0, 0, 0};
position = {0, 0, 0};

compute_position()
{
  t = time();
  acceleration = read_acceleration();
  speed = speed + acceleration * dt;
  position = position + speed * dt;
  dt = time() - t;
}
```

But as I understood, the position will be very inaccurate.

So I have an another idea: take readings from arduino sensors and do all math on PC side using sampling. For example, at the start of the device, I can find out the number of readings per second - RPS. So for 60 FPS I can do RPS/60 samples:

```
get_average_position()
{
   sample_count = RPS / 60;
   buffer = {0, 0, 0};
   position = {0, 0, 0};

   for(sample = 0; sample <  sample_count; ++sample)
   {
       position = compute_position(device.acceleration(), position);
       buffer += position;
   }

   return buffer / sample_count;
}
```

Will this improve accuracy?

In my project, I plan to use MPU9250 that have 3-axis accelerometer/magnetometer/gyroscope. How magnetometer and gyroscope can improve accuracy of position tracking too? I already know that noisy values are filtered using Kalman filter, but I don't sure how it works on MPU basis

P.S. Precision is very important to me. I'm afraid that virtual hands will tremble a lot - that's why I have not ordered MPU9250 yet. Any advice is welcomed, it is very important to me. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: With just an IMU, the position will always drift. You can't get an absolute position that way.

Comment: Seamless (for human) drifts are okay.


What do you mean by absolute position? World-space position?

Comment: And how can I get a position without drifts? (is it possible?)

Comment: https://youtu.be/_q_8d0E3tDk

Comment: Thanks for the video, now I see the problem a little better.

In the context of VR there is a specificity, maybe it can help?: 
1)2-3 MPU are used together
2)Max distance from initial point - the length of the outstretched arm
3)VR trackers used in-room only
4)"Reset trackers position" button is okay.

if I must add new sensors for tracking without drifts, what's the easiest? Cheap? GPS/Kinect are not cheap at all (+GPS is not so good for rooms), maybe camera can be used - but its algorithm seems not to be easy